# nginx map with multiple capture groups results in `[emerg] unknown "a$b" variable`

Tags: regex, nginx

Is it possible to return *multiple* regex capture groups in a nginx `map` block?

This works fine, returning only the first capture group `$a`:

```
map $request_uri $result {
    "~(?<a>.)(?<b>.*)" $a;
    default $request_uri;
}
```

But I can’t return both capture groups as `$a$b`:

```
map $request_uri $result {
    "~(?<a>.)(?<b>.*)" $a$b;
    default $request_uri;
}
```

This causes a `[emerg] unknown "a$b" variable` error message when running `nginx -t`.

The same problem occurs if I use regular numbered regex capture groups (`$1$2`) instead of named capture groups.

Is there any way to do use a map to return multiple regex captures?

I'm using nginx 1.10.3.

Comment: Try with braces, `${a}${b}`.

Comment: This block works correctly on nginx 1.14.2 (the oldest one I have under my control). You can try `${a}${b}` instead, but better upgrade your nginx at least to 1.16.

Comment: I tried with brackets, but it also generates and error: `[emerg] unexpected "{"`. I will see if a newer version of nginx is available for my distro.

Comment: @QuinnComendant Use either single or double quotes:, e.g. `'${a}$[b}'`

Comment: @IvanShatsky Even with single or double quotes, it still gives `unknown "{a}${b}" variable`.

Comment: @QuinnComendant Looks like upgrading the nginx is your only option to make it work. What host OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this thanks to @IvanShatsky. The solution is to upgrade nginx.

Versions of nginx before 1.11.0 do not support returning multiple capture groups. From the [changlog](https://nginx.org/en/CHANGES):

```
Changes with nginx 1.11.0                                        24 May 2016

    *) Feature: the "map" directive supports combinations of multiple
       variables as resulting values.
```